# Non-parametric non-linear regression with deep learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonparametric, deep-learning, nonlinear-regression

I have a situation where I have an increasing list of real numbers $\vec a$ of variable length (generally about 50 numbers but sometimes more). It turns out that these numbers uniquely correspond to two smooth, continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, with $x$ spanning from 0 to 1.

Given a list of numbers $\vec a$, I want to determine what functions $f$ and $g$ gave rise to them.

I can simulate $f$ and $g$ and generate as many lists of numbers $a$ as I need. So the amount of training data is unlimited. A potential complication, however, is that when I simulate $a$, I will get maybe 300 numbers, whereas in real life, most of those numbers will be missing.

I am wondering what tool is best for this task. I was thinking I could use recurrent neural networks. Are they appropriate for this problem?

Comment: Do you think your simulated numbers come from the same function as the real numbers?  If they don't, why do you think they would be useful as training data?  If they do, then you know the function, because you used it in the simulation.

Comment: Hi @jbowman - the situation is actually very complicated - the simulation basically takes a million different things as inputs and produces a million different things as output -- including $f$, $g$, and $\vec a$ -- and there is a relationship between the functions $f$ and $g$ that it outputs to the numbers $\vec a$ that it outputs, but the connection going from $f$ and $g$ to $\vec a$ is extremely complex. Furthermore, being the results of numerical simulations, $f$ and $g$ don't have any kind of closed functional form. Does that clear up your question?

Comment: To be a bit more clear - I can't just pick any $f$ and $g$ that I want. I pick some input parameters $\vec p$ and then evolve the simulation in time. At every time step, I get outputs $f$, $g$, and $\vec a$.

Comment: So to be clear: At one step of your simulation, you get functions $f$ and $g$, both with domain $[0,1]$, which you can use freely to generate numbers, and a set of values $\vec{a}$, which was generated by *one* of those two functions, and you have to determine which one? I suppose you don't have access to the corresponding $x$ values (or it would be trivial to determine which function generated the vector). Is the entire vector $\vec{a}$ generated by one of the functions, or could each element have been generated by either of the functions?

Comment: Sorry @Bridgeburners, I suppose I was unclear. At each time step, my simulation generates $f$, $g$, and $\vec a$ (as well as many other things). The numbers $\vec a$ are not themselves generated, per se, by $f$ and $g$, but instead simply have a relationship to both $f$ and $g$. Actually it is something like $a_i \approx \int F_i f + G_i g \; dx$ where $F_i$ and $G_i$ are also functions that I can also simulate. Currently my approach uses these functions $F$ and $G$ to estimate $f$ and $g$ but relies on many assumptions, and I was hoping to use something like deep learning to skirt them.

Comment: Also, to be extra clear, I don't get any kind of functional form for $f$ and $g$. Instead, I get numerical solutions $f(x_i)$ for $i=1\ldots N$. So I was thinking of fitting splines to $f$ and $g$ and then predicting the values at the spline knots.